# the problem with adding ImageTarget vuforia unity

Tags: 3d

I want to add an ImageTarget image without using the database from the site, namely through the from image parameter inside unity. I add an image to the field and attach a conditional cube to the ImageTarget and place it over the label. When playing the project, I point the camera at the marker, but the cube doesn't appear.

Tried restarting unity and so on did not help vuforia configuration key entered